# Get ISO 8601 date from a date in a string using moment.js

Tags: ionic-framework, momentjs

I have a date stored as a string with the format `"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"`. Is there a way to parse it to ISO 8601 format? I've seen things like `moment(string).format()` and `moment().toISOString()`, but those return `Invalide date` and `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js includes a [format option](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) that allows you to specify a custom format via `moment(time, format)`. Assuming you are using a 24 hour format, you can just use `moment(time, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toISOString()`.

**Note that this will interpret the input string as your timezone and it will return an ISO string in UTC.** If you want the input string to be interpreted as UTC as well then you can use `moment.utc(time, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toISOString()`.

For example, I am currently in the EDT timezone (UTC-4). Here you can see the difference between `moment` and `moment.utc`.

```
> moment("05/09/2011 07:28", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toISOString()
'2011-09-05T11:28:00.000Z'
> moment.utc("05/09/2011 07:28", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toISOString()
'2011-09-05T07:28:00.000Z'
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!